# Using Selenium to close a browser pop-up

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping some data from a website (Investing.com) and occasionally get a pop-up. I've looked for a clickable button in the elements but can't find anything.

Here is the segment from the element page, where the <"i"> element is all I can find relating to the 'X' to close.

```html
...
<div class="right">
    <i class="popupCloseIcon largeBannerCloser">
        ::after
    </i>
...
```

Code I've tried is below:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions as Options
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

d = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
d.get("https://www.investing.com/currencies/eur-usd-technical")

iElements = d.find_elements_by_tag_name("i")
for name in iElements:
    print(name.get_attribute("class"))
    if name.get_attribute("class") == "popupCloseIcon largeBannerCloser":
        print("im here")
        name.click()
```

I print my text and get there, so know I've found my element, but I end up with the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
>   element not interactable

Can't find anything else to interact with though?

Comment: Found this a bit further up, not sure if it helps?

<script>
    $('.js-general-overlay').on('click', $.stopProp);
</script>

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure its not an Alert?
One way to check is to try inspecting elements within the Alert window.

You can try either one of these:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

If that throws a NoAlertPresentException,a screenshot of the popup window might help us help you better.

Comment: Had to retype to :

d.switch_to.alert.dismiss()

Error as follows:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert

This was after my print statement had found it.

Comment: Unfortunately don't have the permissions to post screenshots. https://i.imgur.com/UltYjQP.png

Comment: In the Image, there's a popup panel and an alert grayed in the background.
Since, Selenium threw a NoAlertPresentException, I reckon we need to close the popup first.</br>
Can you ensure a few things here:
1. You are uniquely identifying the right element. When you type the correct xPath or the CssSelector for the element, It should highlight when you hoover on the Searched element.
</br>
2. Element located is displayed and clickable before you Selenium actually clicks it. [Use explicit waits such as "WebDriverWait"]</br>
3. Try using JavaScriptExecutor to click the located element.

Answer (score 1):

Found that I could bypass this by deleting the div element that contains all of the banner. Managed to located this by it's CSS selector and then delete it using some Javascript (copied/pasted).

This then allows my clicks to register so that I can get my elements as required.

Code below tries waiting for the pop-up for 5 seconds, in which case it deletes the element, otherwise it continues trying to click.

```py
delay = 5
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(d, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > div.generalOverlay.js-general-overlay.displayNone.js-promotional')))
    element = d.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.generalOverlay.js-general-overlay.displayNone.js-promotional')
    d.execute_script("var element = arguments[0];element.parentNode.removeChild(element);", element)
    print("Pop-Up Negated")
except TimeoutException:
    print("No Pop-Up Detected")
aElements = d.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for name in aElements:
    if name.get_attribute("href") is not None and "javascript:void" in name.get_attribute("href"):
        if (name.text == i):
            print(name.text)
            name.click()
            break
```

Any comments on improving could would be much appreciated.